# Bind focusout with pressing enter in Javascript in an editable div (not an input)

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to stimulate pressing enter in my html table as being the same as focusout, which currently saves new data and leads to other events upon focusout happening. I do not want to use an input box as I want the table to look streamlined. My table cells are content editable. Here is what I have but I cannot get my key press to be connected to the div.

```
//--->make div editable > start
$(document).on('click', '.row_data', function(event) 
{
    event.preventDefault(); 

    if($(this).attr('edit_type') == 'button')
    {
        return false; 
    }

    //make div editable
    $(this).closest('div').attr('contenteditable', 'true');
    //add bg css
    $(this).addClass('bg-warning').css('padding','5px');

    $(this).focus();


    $(this).attr('original_entry', $(this).html());

})  
//--->make div editable > end
```

Here is what I'm trying to use to stimulate the enter key being pressed leading to a focusout event

```
$('.row_data').keypress(function(e){
if(e.which == 13){
    $(this).blur();    
}
});
```

I cannot tie the blur event to my row_data div. Any suggestions? Currently the enter key only presses tab inside the textbox in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't look like you are listening for the keypress on the same element.

```
$('.row_data').closest('div').attr('content editable', 'true')
```

vs.

```
$('.row_data').keypress(...)
```

try:

```
$('.row_data').closest('div').keypress(...)
```